# <af:popup> triggers browser's popup blocker, how to avoid this?

Tags: jsf, popup, oracle-adf, popup-blocker

How can I enable/disable browser popup blocker from server side?
I am using JSF 2.2 with Oracle ADF. I have a `<af:popup>` which does not work and ask user to off popup blocker in browser. I need to avoid this through coding.

Comment: I know nothing about ADF, but you should basically be using a (modal) dialog instead of a popup window.

Comment: have you tried anything so far ? please post what you tried and what is the code that is not working